# consult download of files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code lists files with pattern gfs.t*... and I also need to check that all of them have a size over 1000 (int(os.path.getsize(file))>1000). But I only get the result about download of the last file of the list. What's wrong in the code? thanks in advance

```
#! /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7

from datetime import datetime
import os
import urllib
import shutil
import multiprocessing
import time
import glob

today = datetime.now()
if today.hour < 14:
   h = "00"
else:
   h = "12"
folder = "/home/Gribs/GFS0.25-p/gfs." + today.strftime('%Y%m%d')+ h

if not os.path.exists(folder):
    os.mkdir("/home/Gribs/GFS0.25-p/gfs." + today.strftime('%Y%m%d')+ h)

os.chdir(folder)
for file in glob.glob("gfs.t*"):
    print (file)

if(int(os.path.getsize(file))>1000):
    print (file + "downloaded right")
else:
    print (file + "not downloaded right")
```

Comment: You need to indent that last `if` block so that it's inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if else block should be indented inside the for loop.

```
   for file in glob.glob("gfs.t*"):
        print (file)

        if(int(os.path.getsize(file))>1000):
            print (file + "downloaded right")
        else:
            print (file + "not downloaded right")
```

Comment: Thanks @Marlon Abeykoon